# ¿Ocupan diferentes longitudes en almacenamiento los campos SQL limitados?

Tags: sql

Me preguntaba si ocupa lo mismo en almacenamiento un campo, por ejemplo VARCHAR. Con una limitación de (64), que uno que tiene, por ejemplo, (5000).

Supongamos que este es el campo:

```
nombre VARCHAR (64)
```

En un registro, lleva el nombre "Pepe". ¿Qué ocurre con los 60 caracteres que caben? ¿Ocupan espacio en disco?

Ya que si es así, sería muy poco óptimo utilizar campos con una longitud muy grande si no se utilizan.

Por lo que yo tengo entendido, el espacio que ocupa es variable. Si almacenas un string de 4 caracteres, ocupará 4 bytes + un prefijo de 1 byte si la longitud es hasta 255 bytes y de 2 bytes si es mayor (no sé si estoy totalmente equivocado).

Entonces, si efectivamente, resulta que el tamaño es adaptable y no ocupan los espacios sobrantes, ¿para qué es el límite de longitud de los campos? ¿Son meras restricciones para controlar que no se almacenen valores demasiado grandes?

Comment: Sí. Para eso es el tamaño que se especifica. VARCHAR de hecho es _variable character_. Lo del tamaño exacto que ocupa, el prefijo que tiene y demás detalles del dato, eso es otra cosa. Pero no, no se reservan los bytes completos

Comment: El el caso de un `VARCHAR` el tamaño ocupado físicamente dependerá de la longitud de la cadena + un pequeño "overhead", es decir la cadena `pepe` almacenada en un `VARCHAR(64)` ocupará el mismo espacio físico que almacenada en un `VARCHAR(5000)`

Comment: De lo poco que recuerdo de SQL, `varchar` se creó pensando precisamente en optimizar el espacio, cosa que se desperdicia con el uso de `char` y `nchar`. Que alguien me corrija si me equivoco. Saludos

Comment: Toma en cuenta que por donde se gana también se pierde. Usar `varchar` tiene una penalización en el rendimiento, ya que obliga a realizar un procedimiento adicional para determinar el tamaño o longitud de la cadena almacenada. En ese caso, usar `char` es más eficiente. Saludos

Comment: Todas son correctas.. casi que da para una respuesta wiki.. jejej

Comment: Entonces, el número de longitud porqué se pone ¿Es solo una restricción?

Comment: Depende de la implementación de SQL, del motor en específico.

Comment: En MySQL, por ejemplo.

Comment: En MySQL depende de varios factores: El mecanismo de almacenamiento (MyISAM, InnoDB, Memory, etc). El tipo de dato (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, etc), el conjunto de caracteres, etc. En algunas combinaciones hay optimizaciones, algunas manejan una parte fija y otra variable, y otras favorecen la velocidad de lectura contra el almacenamiento. En la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) encontrarás un buen punto de partida.